# "Sob hipótese alguma": como saber quando "algum" significa "nenhum"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Um banco disse aos seus clientes:

> Caro cliente, o [Banco] sob hipótese alguma irá solicitar-lhe dados pessoais através de correio electrónico ou contacto telefónico …

Nesta frase "alguma" significa "nenhuma", conforme [uma das definições da palavra](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/algum):

> ## al·gum
>
> 3. Nenhum.

Encontrei este uso de "algum" pela primeira vez nesta frase e, não sei nada sobre este uso. No contexto acima consigo entender que "alguma" significa "nenhuma", porque o contrário seria comportamento terrível por parte do banco. Mas além disso, não consigo entender quando "algum" significa ou não "nenhum", porque **quando estas palavras não têm significados iguais, têm significados opostos,** e porque na frase do banco, **não há outra palavra de sentido negativo no frase.**

Há uma maneira geral para saber se "algum" significa "nenhum" numa frase?

Também, será que existe contextos onde é preferido usar "algum" para significar "nenhum", do que "nenhum" mesmo? Como saber?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O significado do pronome indefinido "algum" depende da sua posição em relação ao substantivo, tem valor positivo quando vem antes e negativo quando vem depois.
Por sua vez o pronome "nenhum" tem sempre valor negativo.
Assim, o pronome "algum" pode substituir o pronome "nenhum" se for usado depois do substantivo:

*"De forma alguma irei jantar consigo."*
*"Em momento algum duvidei de si."*

Answer (score -1):

No Brasil, há muitas formas de se escrever e a "negação de algum' pode ser interpretada como "nenhum" assim como a "afirmação de nenhum" pode também ser vista como "algum".
"ALGUM" e "NENHUM" são palavras brasileiras antônimas. Ou seja, contrárias uma a outra, como "abrir" e "fechar".
Alguns exemplos:

- "Saia dessa casa com ALGUM dinheiro" é exatamente o significado de "ALGUM(A)"
- "NÃO saia de casa de casa com dinheiro ALGUM" é uma negação de "algum" e torna-se "nenhum"
- "Saia dessa casa com NENHUM dinheiro" é exatamente o significado da "NENHUM(A)"
- "NÃO saia dessa casa com NENHUM dinheiro é a negação de "nenhum" e torna-se "algum".

Comment: No Brasil, a palavra "não" é opcional como no exemplo na minha pergunta, ou é sempre preciso?