# "algum amigo" e "amigo algum"?

Tags: significado, gramática, expressões

Qual é deferençe entre "algum amigo" e "amigo algum"?

> Exemplos:
>
> Eu não tenho algum amigo.
>
> Eu não tenho amigo algum.
>
> Resposta alguma está certa.
>
> Alguma resposta está certa.

Comment: Relacionado: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/194/112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comecemos com frases com *algum* (ou, equivalentemente, *nenhum)* após o nome.

> (1) Não tenho **amigo algum**.
>   (2) Não tenho **amigo nenhum**.
>   (3) *Tenho **amigo algum**.
>   (4) *Tenho **amigo nenhum**.
>   (5) **Resposta alguma** está certa.
>   (6) **Resposta nenhuma** está certa.
>   (7) ***Resposta alguma** não está certa.
>   (8) ***Resposta nenhuma** não está certa.

As frases gramaticais acima têm todas um significado negativo. Em (5-8) usei outra construção, porque caso contrário o objeto direto ficaria numa posição muito estranha, mas seria possível dizer, com *amigo algum* sendo agora o sujeito:

> (9) **Amigo algum/nenhum** me viu.

Embora não as considerasse agramaticais, (5-6) e (9) parecem-me, contudo, um pouco infelizes. Preferiria as outras alternativas. A variante com *algum* é usada principalmente em registos escritos.

Repara que o comportamento é semelhante ao de *nada*, outro item de polaridade negativa forte:

> Não tenho **nada**.
>   *Tenho **nada**.
>   **Nada** tenho.
>   ***Nada** não tenho.

Vejamos agora sem inversão, com *algum* preposto ao nome.

> (10) *Eu não tenho **algum amigo**.
>   (11) Eu não tenho **nenhum amigo**.
>   (12) **Nenhuma resposta** está certa.
>   (13) #**Alguma resposta** está certa.
>   (14) #**Nenhuma resposta** não está certa.
>   (15) #**Alguma resposta** não está certa.

Nesta posição relativamente ao nome, **algum** deixa de ter polaridade negativa e passa a ter polaridade positiva. A frase (10) (a tua primeira) é agramatical. As frases (13-15) são gramaticais, mas têm significados diferentes:

- (13): Uma das respostas está certa. A leitura é não específica, i.e., o falante não tem nenhuma resposta particular em mente.
- (14): Esta frase é uma verdadeira dupla negativa. As respostas estão todas certas.
- (15): Uma das respostas está errada. A leitura é não específica.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é que a primeira e a terceira frases, embora gramaticalmente corretas, **não são idiomáticas e tem significado vago e impreciso** Um falante nativo não as diria.

Já a sua segunda frase ficaria mais natural como: **"eu não tenho amigo nenhum"**.
E a quarta frase, fica na dependência do contexto. Eu a usaria na seguinte situação:

a- Você acha que todas as opções são erradas?
b- Não, **alguma resposta está certa**. Só não sei qual.

Em outras situações eu diria:
- **Alguma das respostas está certa**.

Comment: Então por exemplo a primeira e a segunda tem mesma significada?